# How do you test onviewableitemschanged in SectionList?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, jestjs

I have a component that tracks which section of a section list is visible and updates the "active" state based on the visibility of the section.

What I am trying to do is increase the code coverage of Jest to when the visibility does change.

I already have a

```
useEffect( ()=> { sectionListRef.current?.recordInteraction() } )
```

To force the `onViewableItemsChanged` to be called for the initial visible list.  However, I don't see the lines being covered by `jest --coverage`